# Error: Expression must have a class type? Trouble with Class Member Function

Tags: c++, expression

I'm a fairly novice programmer, and I'm having a bit of trouble sorting through this error. While trying to implement the "formatReportLine()" function near the end of main, this error pops up:

```
"2  IntelliSense: expression must have class type"
```

main.cpp

```
    int main()
{
    const string FILENAME("books.txt");

    ifstream input(FILENAME);

    if( input.good() )
    {
        while( !input.eof() )
        {
            string name;
            int type;
            int pages;
            float ounces;
            getline( input, name );
            input >> type >> pages >> ounces;
            input.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); 


            Book newBook( const string& name, Type type, int pages, float ounces );

            cout << newBook.formatReportLine() << endl; //Difficulty with this line

        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File not found: " << FILENAME << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is Book.cpp:

```
//Constructor
Book::Book( const string& name, Type type, int pages, float ounces )
{
    bName = static_cast<string>(name);
    bType = type;
    bPages = pages;
    bOunces = ounces;
    cout << "The constructor is running" << endl;
}

//Default Constructor
Book::Book() {
    bName = "";
    bType = UNKNOWN;
    bPages = 0;
    bOunces = 0.0f;
}

float Book::getWeightLbs()
{
    const float OUNCES = 16.0f;
    return bOunces / OUNCES;
}

string Book::getTypeName()
{
    return TYPE_WORDS[bType];
}

string Book::formatReportLine() 
{
    stringstream reportLine;
    reportLine << Book::getName() << setw(5) << "| Type: " << Book::getTypeName() << setw(5) << "Pages: " 
    << Book::getPages() << setw(5) << "Weight (lbs): " << Book::getWeightLbs();
    string newReportLine;
    reportLine >> newReportLine;
    return newReportLine;
}
```

And finally book.h

```
using namespace std;

enum Type
{
    UNKNOWN = -1,
   PAPERBACK,
    HARDBACK
};

const string TYPE_WORDS[] = { "Paperback", "Hardback" };

class Book
{
public:
    Book();
    //constructor
    Book( const string& name, Type type, int pages, float ounces );
    //destructor
    ~Book(){};

    string formatReportLine();
    float getWeightLbs();   
    string getTypeName();
    //accessors
    string getName(){ return bName; };
    Type getType(){ return bType; };
    int getPages(){ return bPages; };
    float getOunces(){ return bOunces; };

private:
    string bName;  
    Type bType;  
    int bPages;  
    float bOunces;  
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Book newBook(name, type, pages, ounces);`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried that (replacing all instances of newbook in main with that), I got the error   " 2 IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Book::Book" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::string, int, int, float)"

Comment: `Book newBook(name, static_cast<Type>(type), pages, ounces);`

Comment: Ah, Thank you I appreciate it. Still having a bit of trouble with infinite output of "|" but at least that part is fixed.